# Java regex list for interjection/exclamations convert to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have collected a number of Java regular expressions to catch words that  interjection and exclamations [here](https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/341391e262148b8f28bb697f78e26d1b)

So regex look like

```
(G)?(E)?(Y|E|A|H|-){4,} 
B*(R){2,}
B(R)+(A)+(P)+
B+(O){2,}(M)+(B)+
B(O)+MB(A|O)+CL(A)+(T)+
CHA(I|Y)+(A)+
Y(U)+(H)+
```

etc.
Now I want to port these regex dataset to JavaScript, but I would ideally to this process automatically. This because as soon as a new regex is added to that list, it would be converted to JavaScript and then merged via a function like

```
function combine(regex) {
    return new RegExp('(' + regex.map(function (e) {
        var e = e.toString()
        return '(?:' + e.substring(1, e.length - 1) + ')'
    }).join('|') + ')',"gi");
}
```

An attempt I did was the following, assumed to have all the Java regex in the string array `screamsRegex`:

```
   var text = "how are oh-oh-oh you uu oo today";
   screamsRegex.forEach(regex => {
        const RegExpObj = new RegExp("\\b(" + regex + ")\\b","gi");
        const match = text.match(RegExpObj);
        if(match) console.log(regex,text.match(RegExpObj) );
    });
```

and eventually combine all those regex together to find the matching patterns in text doing

```
const combinedRegex = combine(screamsRegexList.map(r=>'/'+r+'/'));
```

but it does not seem to work as expected for a given text with multiple patterns

```
(.{2,}?)([\s|-]*\1.?[\s|-]*){2,} [ 'how are oh-oh-oh you uu oo today' ]
((.)*-(.)*){2,} [ 'how are oh-oh-oh you uu oo today' ]
.*(\D)\1{2,}.+ [ 'how are oh-oh-oh you uu oo today' ]
.+(\D)\1{2,}.* [ 'how are oh-oh-oh you uu oo today' ]
OH [ 'oh', 'oh', 'oh' ]
(O|A|H|-){3,} [ 'oh-oh-oh' ]
(O|U|H|-){3,} [ 'oh-oh-oh' ]
(W|H|O|A|-){5,} [ 'oh-oh-oh' ]
(O|U|-){2,} [ 'uu', 'oo' ]
(U|H|-){2,} [ 'uu' ]
```

Comment: I don’t see any Java here.

Comment: How are you using that list in Java?

Comment: *Curious:* Why are there so many unnecessary parentheses in the regex's? E.g. `B(R)+(A)+(P)+` is the same as `BR+A+P+`

Comment: @VGR I’m using these regex patterns into Java framework that is parsing the text. My aim here was to find a way (if there is any) to convert each pattern into valid JavaScript RegExp objects, because most of the syntax seems to match, but not completely I guess.

Comment: @Andreas I think the aim was to have capture groups in that case.

Comment: You're correct that Java's and JavaScript's regex engine don't fully support the same patterns, but your list doesn't seem to use any features that aren't the same in both, so I don't see what your problem is. *"does not seem to work"* is not a description we can respond to. You need to be more *specific*.

Comment: @Andreas yes thank you. So basically if you look at the provided example, the pattern matched were not the pattern I was searching for (for the injections `oh`, `uh`, eventually repeated with hyphen in `oh-oh`). And if we try other examples this happens, even before combining the regex together it happens, I assume due to those differences between Java and JavaScript regex parser syntax.

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Please see "[How to create a **Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Which means that you should pick an example pattern and show code and output in both Java and JavaScript where the output differs (since that is what you claim is the problem, if I understand you correctly).

Comment: E.g. as far as I can find, the first example matches `"oh-oh-oh "` in both Java and JavaScript, so that's not an example of a discrepancy between the two. --- See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/I1b2M8/1) for JavaScript version of that one.